# How apply kfold cross validation using tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, k-fold

My aim is to apply k-fold cross-validation for training a VGG19 model. In order to do so, I read my images from directory using the following code:

```
DIR = "/Images"
data_dir = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd() + '\\Images')

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(224, 224),
  batch_size=32)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(224, 224),
  batch_size=32)
```

and it worked properly without using kfold cross-validation. But when I want to use K-fold cross-validation, I have to have the label and images for `train_ds` separately, and I couldn't find a solution for that, except I need to read images using another method. Therefore, I have decided to read images using `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory`. But as far as I understand, in order to load images using `flow_from_directory`, I have to have two separate subsets as `traning` and `test` in images, while I don't have `traning` and `test` folders in my case. Is there any solution for either of these approaches?

Furthermore, using the first method, which is `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`, the number of images that will find is different from `flow_from_directory`.
Here is the output of the first method:

**Found 1060 files belonging to 4 classes.
Using 848 files for training.**

Here is the output of the second approach:

```
img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0 / 255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    vertical_flip=True)
Wheat_data = img_gen.flow_from_directory(data_dir,
                                         subset="training",
                                         seed=123)
```

**Found 849 images belonging to 4 classes.**

Answer (score 9):

You could convert your datasets to `numpy` arrays and it should work as usual:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size)

train_images = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y:x)))
train_labels = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y:y)))

val_images = np.concatenate(list(val_ds.map(lambda x, y:x)))
val_labels = np.concatenate(list(val_ds.map(lambda x, y:y)))

inputs = np.concatenate((train_images, val_images), axis=0)
targets = np.concatenate((train_labels, val_labels), axis=0)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)

for train, test in kfold.split(inputs, targets):
  
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(180, 180, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
  history = model.fit(inputs[train], targets[train],
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=2)
  scores = model.evaluate(inputs[test], targets[test], verbose=0)
```

Or you can use `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` with a batch size of 1 and `shuffle=False` but it is not so efficient:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 1

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  shuffle = False)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  shuffle = False)

ds = train_ds.concatenate(val_ds)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)

for train, test in kfold.split(np.arange(len(ds))):
  train = [x+1 for x in train]
  test = [x+1 for x in test]
  train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([ds.skip(t-1).take(t) for t in train]).flat_map(lambda x: x).map(lambda x, y: (x[0, ...], y[0, ...]))
  test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([ds.skip(t-1).take(t) for t in test]).flat_map(lambda x: x).map(lambda x, y: (x[0, ...], y[0, ...]))
  train_ds = train_ds.take(len(train)).batch(64, drop_remainder=True)
  test_ds = test_ds.take(len(test)).batch(64, drop_remainder=True)
  
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(180, 180, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
  history = model.fit(train_ds,
              epochs=2)
  scores = model.evaluate(test_ds, verbose=0)
```

Another option would be to use dictionaries to store indices and tensors:

```
#...
ds = train_ds.concatenate(val_ds)

lookup_images = {}
lookup_labels = {}
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(ds):
  lookup_images[i] = x
  lookup_labels[i] = y

kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)

for train, test in kfold.split(np.arange(len(ds))):

  images_train = np.concatenate(list(map(lookup_images.get, train)))
  labels_train = np.concatenate(list(map(lookup_labels.get, train)))

  images_test = np.concatenate(list(map(lookup_images.get, test)))
  labels_test = np.concatenate(list(map(lookup_labels.get, test)))

  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(180, 180, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
  history = model.fit(images_train, labels_train, epochs=2)
  scores = model.evaluate(images_test, labels_test, verbose=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. For adding argumentation, can I just add `tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2)` (or any other), after `Rescaling`and before first `Conv2D` layer?
And is it possible to use `Dataset.prefetch` while we split the dataset? like [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#configure_the_dataset_for_performance)

Comment: To your first question: Yes. To your second question: you can try experimenting with dataset.prefetch but I am not sure if it will have so much of an affect on the performance.

Comment: Thanks again. BTW, I run the first approach on my machine and faced this Error `InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.` but when I used google collab, it was fine. I thought it is the cause of GPU memory, and `batch size`, and I reduced it to `16` but still got the same error on my machine. any idea?

Comment: I don't think so, my tf version is 2.6. The code will run for the first two epochs for training the first model using KFold, but for training the second model I will get that Error. Have you tried the first code on your machine or just used collab?

Comment: Hmm just colab actually.. all approaches ran without any problems.

Comment: The same is here. For some reason, I cannot run the code on my machine, and it will show `ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,16,180,180] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc` error as well, Please let me know if in any case, you run your code on your machine and it succeeds.