# How to do k-Fold Cross Validation with tf.data.Dataset API?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tf.data.dataset

It easy to do k-Fold Cross Validation by using scikit-learn package. There we separately use data and labels. However, here combine data and labels before feeding into model. like:

```
 tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
        .shuffle(batch_size * 100)
        .batch(batch_size)
```

In this case how to do K-fold cross validation?

Comment: What is `X` and `Y`?

Comment: X is input data  suppose 333456,6 and y is labels 333456

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/fenwickslab/fenwicks/blob/2d539634efe829bd5a2e2c1b9c837819a89bb707/data.py#L370

Comment: @AloneTogether it is not clear and complex one. Can you describe by using some toy example?

Comment: First try, then we can take a look.

Comment: I simply ignore to use sickit-lern package for cross validation. I manually implemented by me self. Here is the code: `cvscores = []
for i in range(3):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size = 0.1)
    model = modeling(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
    f_score = test_model(X_test, y_test)
    cvscores.append(f_score)

sum=0;
for j in range(3):
    print(f"CrossFold: {i}", cvscores[i])
    sum=sum+cvscores[i]

average = sum/3
print(f"average: {average}")`. Please verify this code?

Comment: Have you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676222/how-apply-kfold-cross-validation-using-tf-keras-utils-image-dataset-from-directo/71678692#71678692